# Pumping Bytes Directly into Response.OutputStream - how to deal with byte count?

Tags: c#, iis

I have a need to transfer large streams of data from a web service.  Rather than increase the IIS buffer size in the metabase, I'd like to pump the bytes directly into the unbuffered Response.OutputStream.

```
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
Response.Buffer = false;
int len = GetReport(protocolName, sourceName, reportName, pageIndex, pageSize, Response.OutputStream);
Response.End();
```

This works fine, but I can only know how many bytes have been retrieved *after* retrieving them, so I can't set the ContentLength header.  The following line throws an exception (can't add headers after you start returning content):

```
int len = GetReport(protocolName, sourceName, reportName, pageIndex, pageSize, Response.OutputStream);
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", len.ToString()); // can't do this
```

**Question:** I guess there really aren't many options.  I suppose the only way to handle this would be to introduce an intermediate stream, e.g., memory stream, get the length of the stream, set the header, and then pump *that* stream into the Response.Output stream.  Any other ideas?'

Comment: Yes, I can modify the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`content-length` is not required.  If you legitimately don't know it prior to sending content to the response stream, then leave it out.  The browser will still display the result fine, but will not be able to provide a progress bar or percentage completion.  If the content is small, then this is not a major concern.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13

> In HTTP, it SHOULD be sent whenever the message's length can be determined prior to being transferred

That's SHOULD and not MUST.

Comment: Thanks.  In this case, there's no way to buffer and determine the content in advance.  I'll have to handle it in the web service call.  I knew that the content would be successfully transferred; I just wanted to be sure that I wasn't missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the function to give the length before writing the data.

For example, you could make it take an `Action<long>` callback, then call the callback with the length before writing to the stream.
Your page could then pass `length => Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", length.ToString())` as the callback.

Comment: You would still have to introduce a second stream - inside the function in your case.  You can't fill the Response.OutputStream without flushing it.  Failing to flush it as you go will result in an OutOfMemory Exception.  And by flushing it, you can't write the header.  Perhaps I shouldn't have asked the question...a second stream is really the only option, I think.

Comment: @Brett: You're misunderstanding my answer.  You can call the `Action<long>` before you start writing to the stream.

Comment: If you have a data source of indeterminate size (records from a database), how would you write the length without reading the data?  You have to put the data somewhere as you read it.  The most efficient place is to put it in the Response.OutputStream.  But that requires periodic flushing to avoid an OutofMemory exception.

Comment: That's a separate question.  You might be able to modify the method to calculate the size before writing the report, depending on how it works.